# RxJs unsubscribe unsibscribes future subscriptions

Tags: rxjs

In RxJs unsubscribe unsibscribes future subscriptions. Why and how to fix it?

Here is what I mean:

```
import { interval, Subscription } from "rxjs";

const subs = new Subscription();
subs.unsubscribe();

const sub = interval(1000).subscribe(r => console.log(r));
subs.add(sub);
```

I would expect this code to infinitely output integers. But it outputs nothing. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call unsubscribe on a `Subscription` it'll change its status to closed
If there is any future added subscribe when it subscription is closed, it'll unsubscribe all the future pass in subscription immediately

Here is the part of the source code in older `Subscription` class `.add` method

```
         case 'object':
            if (subscription.closed || typeof subscription.unsubscribe !== 'function') {
                return subscription;
            }
            else if (this.closed) {
                subscription.unsubscribe();
                return subscription;
            }
            else if ....
```